# How to figure out which lines of css is not actually affecting anything again?

Tags: css

I changed the html multiple times,but without deleting the related css specification.

And now there are quite some useless css there.

Is there an efficient solution to grep all them?

Comment: Firebug isn't enough? www.getfirebug.com

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's an excellent plugin for FireFox called [DustMe](http://www.sitepoint.com/dustmeselectors/) that you can try.

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly DreamWeaver has that functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Google search turned up some tools:

[Dust Me](http://www.sitepoint.com/dustmeselectors/)
[Detecting Unused CSS Selectors](http://www.aggiorno.com/blogs/aggiornings/post/Detecting-unused-CSS-selectors-.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

Get firebug, and then you can see what's redundant and try getting rid of css rules and see if it makes a difference!

Comment: @cemkalyoncu, cleaning code always takes a lot of time. That's why there's so much messy code out there: people don't take the time.